# How to link out to url and then on exit return to the original url

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to this so I will apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.  Here is what I am trying to do.  We have an online training program where a student watches some video and then the program stops and asks the student some questions.  If they get the question right, they move on, if not they have to re-watch that video portion which basically gives them the answer.  Then at certain points in the training, we link out to another url which tests their skills even further.  When that lesson is done, they click the "exit" button and I need them to return to the spot where they left off originally.  Right now, the code below (had to take out a couple of carrots to get it to show up) is what I am using to link to the other url.  What happens though is when they hit "exit" instead of going back to the screen where they launched from originally, it goes back to another window that is open to launch the training in the first place.  The window I want them to go back to is behind this other window.

Ideally, what I would like is to have a have a screen come up that says "launch skillbuilder lesson" and also something that says the "Skillbuilder lesson is not complete", then it opens up the new url in a separate window, when they are finished, they click on the exit button and it returns to the original window they left off from.  When they return to the original window, it now says, "Skillbuilder lesson complete". And they can move on.

From the "searching" I have done, it seems like I probably have to use some java script to do this??  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
{{ <a href="http://paulson.recol.com/paulsonskillbuilderactivex/OP_sim01/sim.htm" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="http://www.epathcampus.com/Paulson/optnew/opt1_new/images/sklbldrbkgd1.jpg" style="border:none;"/>
   </a>
```

Comment: Why not just have the link open in a new window using `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't own both sites (on different domains) which means you either need access to the other domain to use JavaScript, or you have to work-around the cross-domain obstacle. one work-around, if you need to, is use an `<iframe>` so you can render the external site, but wrap it in code *you* can control (such as an `Exit` button like you mentioned). e.g.

Original Page:

```
<!-- content -->
<a href="external?site=http://someothersite.com">External link</a>
<!-- content -->
```

`external` is just a generic handler that creates a page like:

```
<!-- content -->
<iframe src="http://someothersite.com"></iframe>
<a href="origin">exit</a>
<!-- content -->
```

And `origin` is just a link back to the referring page.

Comment: Google AdSense prohibits displaying sites on websites displaying other un-owned sites in iframes.